# Python global variable indentation

Tags: python, indentation, vizard

We are using Vizard to program a software
It uses Python but we are quite new at it and we get this error:

```
Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

in the marked line. Any idea why?

```
import viz
import math
import viztask

count = 0
boolTime = False

viz.setMultiSample(4)
viz.fov(20)
viz.go()

viz.phys.enable()
viz.phys.setGravity( [0, 0, 0] )
viz.window.setFullscreen()

viz.setOption('viz.model.apply_collada_scale',1)
ball = viz.add('ball.dae')
ball.setPosition([-0.1,1.5,4])
#ball.setScale([0.75,0.75,0.75])
ball.collideSphere()


viz.setOption('viz.model.apply_collada_scale',1)
path = viz.addChild('path.dae')
path.setPosition([-1,1.0,4])
path.collideMesh()

#collision
path.enable(viz.COLLIDE_NOTIFY)
def onCollide(e):
        global count 
        count = count+1
        print(count)

viz.callback( viz.COLLIDE_BEGIN_EVENT, onCollide )

#mouse
viz.mouse.setOverride(viz.ON) 
link = None 
def grabBall():
    global link
    link = viz.grab( viz.Mouse, ball )
    boolTime = True                    # ERROR HERE

def releaseBall():
    global link
    link.remove()
    link = None

def TestReactionTime():
    while boolTime:
        #Wait for next frame to be drawn to screen
        d = yield viztask.waitDraw()

        #Save display time
        displayTime = d.time

        #Wait for keyboard reaction
        d = yield viztask.waitMouseUp(viz.MOUSEBUTTON_LEFT)

        #Calculate reaction time
        reactionTime = d.time - displayTime
        print(reactionTime)

vizact.onmousedown(viz.MOUSEBUTTON_LEFT, TestReactionTime)
vizact.onmousedown(viz.MOUSEBUTTON_LEFT,grabBall)
vizact.onmouseup(viz.MOUSEBUTTON_LEFT,releaseBall)
```

Comment: Please do *NOT* postprocess code with syntax errors.

Comment: You're most likely mixing tabs and spaces. Make sure your editor inserts 4 spaces for each level of indentation and no tabs.

Comment: Also, boolTime needs a `global` just like the link variable in that function if you want to keep the changes.

Comment: Okay, it was because of both, the tab and the global things. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had tabs instead of 4 spaces.

Thank you!